# how to pass parameter to javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following javascript.

```
<script>
function getMethod(id){alert(id);}

</script>
```

following is html,

```
<table id="tbl1">
<tr>
<td><input type="button" onclick="getMethod()"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I need to pass table id "tbl1" to javascript method getMethod on click event of html button. so what should I do? what I want is something like this,(Passing table ID onclick method's parameters)

```
<input type="button" onclick="getMethod('$("tbl1").ID')"/>
```

how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="getMethod(this)"/> this will be enough and then you can fetch the id from this in getMethod

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't pass anything rather than the `this` reference and do,

HTML

```
<input type="button" onclick="getMethod(this)"/>
```

JS

```
function getMethod(elem){
   alert($(elem).closest('table').attr('id'));
}
```

In the above function we have used `.closest()` to grab the parent table. and we have used `.attr('id')` to retrieve its id.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Lt4ex/)

Comment: @RobSchmuecker `parents` can't be more efficient than `closest` since the `parents` looks at all ascendants while `closest` stops at the first `table` it finds - which is all that is needed here.

Answer (score 4):

```
<input type="button" onclick="getMethod('tbl1')"/>
```

Update, since your comment made it clear this needs to be more 'dynamic'

Here is a vanilla javascript implementation:

```
function getMethod(element) {
        // element -> td -> tr -> tbody ->table
        parentTable = element.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
        alert(parentTable.id);
    }
```

Called using :

```
<input type="button" onclick="getMethod(this)" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/MxWR7/1/

Comment: actually the ids genetate dynamically and there can be any number of tables. So I need something more automated

Comment: OK - in which case I would recommend one of the jQuery solutions

Comment: @abc how you generate ids?

Answer (score 2):

Pass only **this**:

```
<input type="button" onclick="getMethod(this)"/>
```

In your functuon write this:

```
<script>
    function getMethod(idget) {
        alert($(idget).closest("table").attr("id"));
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged the question with jquery, You dont have to write inline code for click handler

```
<table id="tbl1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jquery code will be

```
$("#tbl1 button").click(function () {
    alert($(this).closest("table").attr("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it is much better to add event listeners through javascript than inline. So assuming you use jQuery on the page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //'#myButton' should be some jQuery identifier for your button
    $('#myButton').click(function(e) {
        getMethod('tbl1');
    });
});
```

Then in your html for the button:

```
<input type="button" id="myButton">
```

And you're done! If you need some programmatic way to identify the parent of your element, look at [$.parents()].[1](http://api.jquery.com/parents/)